# Question on compound interest

Tags: sequences-and-series

If you deposit $100 at the end of every month into an
account that pays 3% interest per year compounded monthly,the amount of interest accumulated after months is given by the sequence.

I tried the following method to solve it

I used geometric seq sum of nth term but in actual formula a minus n(number of months). is present.Can anyone please derive the equation for Interest after n months.

Thanks

Comment: I edited the title, as I see neither infinite sequence nor series here.

Answer (score 1):

The total value of all the payments and the accumulated interest, at $i=0.0025,$ is given by$$100+100(1+i)+100(1+i)^2+100(1+i)^3+...+100(1+i)^{n-1}$$The last payment accumulates zero interest, and the first payment compounds for $n-1$ months. The sum of this geometric series, $S$, is given by:$$S=\frac{100((1+i)^n-1).}{i}$$ You then need to subtract $100n$ from this total to find the interest portion.

Answer (score 0):

The principal + interest after one month  $=100\left(1+\frac 3{12}\cdot\frac1{100}\right)=100\left(1+\frac1{400}\right)$

The principal + interest after two months  $=100\left(1+\frac1{400}\right)\left(1+\frac1{400}\right)=100\left(1+\frac1{400}\right)^2$

The principal + interest after $n$ months  $=100\left(1+\frac1{400}\right)^n$ where integer $n\ge0$

So, the interest after $n$ months  $=100\left(1+\frac1{400}\right)^n-100$

Comment: Bu the Formula i got involved 100(1.0025^n -1/.0025) and the formula as given in problem involves 100(1.0025^n -1/.0025) - n.

Comment: @joe1983, my result can be expressed as $100\left((1.0025)^n-1\right)$. Btw, did you follow my method?

Comment: I followed the geometric sequence nth sum formula. The problem can be found on page 701 exercise 11.1 question 66 James Stewart Calculus 7E Early Transcendentals.

Comment: I found your method easier Thanks @lab bhattacharjee

Comment: @joe1983, nice to hear that.

Comment: What about the other $n-1$ payments?  There's one made every month, and they all accumulate interest